# How to set dynamic parameters value in jqueryUI widgets plugin "Multi-date-picker"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-multidatespicker

I tried to make a multi date selector calendar with jqueryUI and came to know about a plugin named "Multi-Dates-Picker". The problem with that is that I could not dynamically set the value in the usual way of a setter method in jqueryUI widgets, while the getter method works fine.

```js
var date = new Date();
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = (new Date()).setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

function myFunction() {
  $('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker({
    minDate: 3, // today
    maxDate: 15, // +30 days from today
    maxPicks: 2,
  });
}

function maxpicksup() {
  // Setter
  $("#mdp-demo").datepicker("option", "maxDate", 21);
  $("#mdp-demo").datepicker("option", "minDate", 0);
  //setter
  $("#mdp-demo").datepicker("option", "maxPicks", 5);
  // Getter
  var firstDay = $("#mdp-demo").datepicker("option", "maxPicks");
  alert(firstDay);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-multidatespicker@1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-multidatespicker@1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div class="" id="mdp-demo"></div>
  <button onclick="maxpicksup()">click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Use the `addDates` option, as outline in the documentation: https://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#option-addDates

Comment: hmm, thats right, but actually my problem is how to change the value of parameter **maxpicks** dynamically

Comment: You can see in the docs that the plugin doesn't support changing those options after initialisation. You'll need to destroy the instance and recreate it